# Automate entering some sites

Tags: web

This question is not language specific and despite making some research at the Internet, I haven't found barely *anything*.

The question is if there is a way to enter automatically some sites once a day (or at the startup of the computer)?

I have worked some times with Selenium lib for Python, but I would like to do something more "in the background", without noticing that these pages have been visited.

***Note:*** I don't mean to make my browser open pre-defined tabs when I open it. Just visiting some authenticated pages).

Comment: What do you mean by "enter automatically some sites"?  Pretty much any language/platform/etc. has a way to invoke HTTP requests, and any application you write can be scheduled to run daily.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the background, without noticing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean 'headless' by 'in the background'?

Take a look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)